# Prepared statements for INSERT INTO xxx () VALUES (), (), (), ... of a variable number of records?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to frequently insert a bunch of records into a table. Instead of inserting them one by one which is not efficient, I insert them in batches with INSERT INTO () VALUES (), (), (), ..., wherein it isn't a fixed number of records in each batch. Sometimes it's 20 records but sometimes it's 56, etc.

Thus far I can only build prepared statements with a pre-determined number of parameters such as these [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

So how to build a prepared statement for a query like "INSERT INTO xxx () VALUES (), (), (), ..." wherein the number of records after VALUES are not pre-determined?

Comment: I think less problematic is to run the query *n* times.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Why not use a prepared statement with 1 value and execute that a bunch? It's probably faster.

Comment: The whole point of a prepared statement is that it is compiled by the DB server so that you can call it multiple times without the overhead. Therefore there's really no need to run an insert with multiple records. Just set it up to run for a single record, and run it as many times as needed.

Comment: Please see here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php - "Also, consider the use of the MySQL multi-INSERT SQL syntax for INSERTs. For the example, multi-INSERT requires less round-trips between the server and client than the prepared statement shown above. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use something like this:

```
<?php
// pdo example

$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (:value1, :value2, :value3)';

// $dbh is pdo connection
$insertTable = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$countArray = count($array);
$i = 0;

while ($i < $countArray) {
   $insertTable->bindParam(':value1', $array['value1'][$i], PDO::PARAM_INT); // if value is int
   $insertTable->bindParam(':value2', $array['value2'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR); // if value is str
   $insertTable->bindParam(':value3', $array['value3'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $insertTable->execute();

   $i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out something interesting here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

See "Example #4 Less round trips using multi-INSERT SQL":

> Also, consider the use of the MySQL multi-INSERT SQL syntax for
>   INSERTs. For the example, multi-INSERT requires less round-trips
>   between the server and client than the prepared statement shown above.

```
<?php
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)")) {
    echo "Multi-INSERT failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
?>
```

After some tests with microtime() it seems to me it is indeed better to stick to the multi-insert syntax rather than prepared statements if there are quite a few records (e.g. 50) to be inserted at a time.